# SSH auth by public key not working for one user on a system

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, sshd, public-key

I can't setup public key authentication for one particular user on a system. I checked user home and .ssh directories permissions, and it's good (drwx------. both, the same as for other users that can auth by public key). I found somewhere in the internets an advice to stop sshd and run it with -ddd option to get some more information (sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd). The weird thing that if I run it that way then it's working for the user.

Any ideas on this strange behavior?

Comment: are the file ownerships correct?

Comment: Also, you said you checked directory permissions, but did you also check key permission in the user's .ssh directory? If all fails, issue a different key.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Try the proper SELinux file security context.

```
# restorecon -Rv /home/troubleduser/.ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was SELinux (Security Enhanced Linux) preventing sshd reading authorization keys in user's directory. I checked that it was enabled with `sestatus`, I disabled it with echo 0 >/selinux/enforce and it started to work. I disabled it permanently in /etc/selinux/config

Comment: Ouch!  Now all nefarious insiders have SELinux disabled access.  How about changing the SELinux context of the appropriate files instead and re-enabling SELinux?